# How to Remove Outline/Border from Object SVG in IE11

Tags: html, css, svg

How to remove the Outline/Border in Object SVG in IE11

I tried with `border:0 & outline: 0` but it not working. Outine coming only in IE..
I need to border below the text SVG Content
[image]

```html
      <object> SVG Content
     <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
       <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80"/>
     </svg>
    </object>
```

Comment: svg border calls:stroke see more here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes

Comment: and add your code please

Comment: I see no outline when I view this snippet on IE11.  The border must be being added by something else on your page.

Answer (score 2):

SVG border calls [`stroke`](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_stroking.asp)

try remove it with:

```
svg {
    stroke: transparent;
    stroke-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: OP's SVG has no stroke.  So this solution won't help in this case.